# Is there a better way to access nested maps and vectors in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I'm grabbing some json from [here on freebase](http://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?query=%7B%22query%22%3A+%5B%7B%0A++%22id%22%3A+++null%2C%0A++%22name%22%3A+null%2C%0A++%22type%22%3A+%22%2Flaw%2Flegal_case%22%2C%0A++%22court%22%3A+%5B%7B%0A++++%22id%22%3A+++++++null%2C%0A++++%22optional%22%3A+true%2C%0A++++%22name%22%3A+++++%5B%5D%0A++%7D%5D%2C%0A++%22subject%22%3A+%5B%7B%0A++++%22id%22%3A+++++++null%2C%0A++++%22optional%22%3A+true%2C%0A++++%22name%22%3A+++++%5B%5D%0A++%7D%5D%2C%0A++%22%2Fcommon%2Ftopic%2Farticle%22%3A+%5B%7B%0A++++%22id%22%3A+++++++++null%2C%0A++++%22optional%22%3A+++true%2C%0A++++%22source_uri%22%3A+%5B%5D%0A++%7D%5D%2C%0A++%22%2Flaw%2Flegal_case%2Fparties%22%3A+%5B%7B%0A++++%22id%22%3A+++++++null%2C%0A++++%22optional%22%3A+true%2C%0A++++%22parties%22%3A++%5B%5D%2C%0A++++%22role%22%3A+%5B%7B%0A++++++%22id%22%3A+%5B%5D%0A++++%7D%5D%0A++%7D%5D%0A%7D%5D%7D) (careful, you can only request this a few times without using `&key=your-key`).

I want to convert the response into something similar to this:

```
    ({:case "Roe v. Wade", :plaintiffs ("Norma McCorvey"), :defendants ("Henry Wade"), :court "Supreme Court of the United States", :subjects ("Abortion" "Privacy"), :article "http://wp/en/68493"} ...)
```

Here's the code I came up with after using clojure.data.json/read-string:

```
    (defn extract-data [case]
      {:case (case "name")
       :plaintiffs (flatten (map #(get % "parties") (filter (fn [p] (some #(= (% "id") "/en/plaintiff") (p "role")))
                                                           (case "/law/legal_case/parties"))))
       :defendants (flatten (map #(get % "parties") (filter (fn [p] (some #(= (% "id") "/en/defendant") (p "role")))
                                                           (case "/law/legal_case/parties"))))
       :court (get-in case ["court" 0 "name"])
       :subjects (map #(% "name") (case "subject"))
       :article (get-in case ["/common/topic/article" 0 "source_uri" 0])})

    (def response (-> query-uri
                       java.net.URL.
                       slurp
                       json/read-str))
    (def case-data (map extract-data (response "result")))
```

extract-data seems overly complex though, is there a better way to do this? Is this a case where core.logic could be used? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a look a different query systems (zip-filters, core.logic, datomic's datalog on collections etc.). Or roll your own ad-hoc one:

```
(defn select [x path]
  (if-let [[p & ps] (seq path)]
    (if (fn? p)
      (mapcat #(select % ps) (filter p x))
      (recur (get x p) ps))
    x))

(def mapping
  {:case ["name"]
   :plaintiffs ["/law/legal_case/parties"
                #(= (get-in % ["role" 0 "id" 0]) "/en/plaintiff")
                "parties"]
   :defendants ["/law/legal_case/parties"
                #(= (get-in % ["role" 0 "id" 0]) "/en/defendant")
                "parties"]
   :court ["court" 0 "name" 0]
   :subjects ["subject" (constantly true) "name"]
   :article ["/common/topic/article" 0 "source_uri" 0]})

(defn extract-data [x mapping]
  (into {}
    (for [[k path] mapping]
      [k (if (some fn? path) (select x path) (get-in x path))])))
```

And then (map #(extract-data % mapping) results) should do the trick

```
=> (extract-data (first result) mapping)
{:case "Roe v. Wade", :plaintiffs ("Norma McCorvey"), :defendants ("Henry Wade"), :court "Supreme Court of the United States", :subjects ("Abortion" "Privacy"), :article "http//wp/en/68493"}
```

This type of code (the query interpreter) may be brittle, so be sure to have a test suite.

Answer (score 0):

[Specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter) can help.

```
(ns stackoverflow-answer.core
  (:require [com.rpl.specter :refer :all]))

; your example data
(def case {"name" "Roe v. Wade"
           "/law/legal_case/parties" [{"role" [{"id" "/en/plaintiff"}]
                                       "parties" ["Norma McCorvey"]}
                                      {"role" [{"id" "/en/defendant"}]
                                       "parties" ["Henry Wade"]}]
           "court" [{"name" "Supreme Court of the United States"}]
           "subject" [{"name" "Abortion"}
                      {"name" "Privacy"}]
           "/common/topic/article" [{"source_uri" ["http://wp/en/68493"]}]})

(defn specter-extract [case]
  {:case (case "name")
   :plaintiffs (select ["/law/legal_case/parties"
                        ALL
                        (selected? "role" ALL "id" (pred= "/en/plaintiff"))
                        "parties"
                        ALL]
                       case)
   ; etc
   })
```

Usage:

```
stackoverflow-answers.core=> (specter-extract case)
{:case "Roe v. Wade", :plaintiffs ["Norma McCorvey"]}
```